# Backbone to use Underscore templates with helpers

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to use helper functions with Underscore templates and Backbone.
Now I'm doing it this way:

View:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    template: getTpl('#b_ezlo', 1),
    // ...
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    }
});
```

Template getter:
Here I generally return the template, along with the helper functions.
The problem is when I do `prepare` I cannot return the helper functions, because it will require to return also other variables for the template, and it causes `undefined getDisabledState`:

```
function getTpl(tpl, options) {
    if (!tpl) return;
    if (!options) options = null;
    var prepare = false;
    if (options == 1) {
        // this is called on View initialization
        // with template: getTpl('#b_ezlo', 1),
        options = {};
        prepare = true;
    }

    var viewHelpers = {}

    if (tpl == "#b_view") {
        console.log("prepare", prepare);
        viewHelpers.getDisabledState = function() {
            if (typeof options.disabled != "undefined") {
                return options.disabled;
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }

    _.extend(options, viewHelpers);

    if (prepare) {
        return _.template($(tpl).html());
    } else {
        return _.template($(tpl).html())(options);
    }
}
```

And part of template (Jade) where I want to use the helper:

```
.icon-block(data-disabled!="<% if (typeof getDisabledState != 'undefined') {getDisabledState()} %>")
```

What I dislike here is `if (typeof getDisabledState != 'undefined')` part, which is not nice to have in the template.

**So if there is any other way to prepare templates with helper functions?**

Comment: I think u can checkout same task realization in MarionetteJS. There is templateHelpers feature quite close to your task.

Comment: What about Backbone+Marionette+Handlebars schema? Handlebars has a build in `registerHelper`, and your can declare your custom helpers.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @VahanVardanyan. I do like Handlebars, but the big part of project is already working with Underscore template, should stay within it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Evgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571284/evgeniy)'s comment, most probably will do it the MarionetteJS way - defining helpers in the View.

http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers